# Manually Pruning a Decision Tree

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, rpart, pruning

I have generated a simple tree using the `rpart()` function, however I would like to be able to stop the second split at `Petal.Length < 4.9` before it splits by `Petal.Width`, however I would not like to alter anything else in the tree. The only thing that I have found is that I can use the subset function in order to manually grow the tree, but this process can be very tedious. Any suggestions on a function that could possibly be used? The code used to generate the tree is:

```
library(rpart)

library(datasets)

data("iris")

library(rpart.plot)


Sample <-sample.int(n = nrow(iris), size = floor(.7*nrow(iris)), replace = F)

train <- iris[Sample, ]

test <- iris[-Sample, ]

m1 <- rpart(Species~Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
            data = train, control = rpart.control(cp = 0.005), method = "anova")

rpart.plot(m1, type = 3, fallen.leaves = TRUE)
```

[Decision Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw7Ew.png)

Comment: You should also learn to build reproducible examples with `set.seed()`. When I run your code I don't even get a split on "Petal.Width".

Comment: Thank you I added that. That split was just an example though, I would ideally like to be able to apply this logic to a much larger tree

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the `snip` argument of `rpart.plot`:

```
trimmed.tree <- rpart.plot(m1, snip=TRUE))$obj   # manually trim the tree
rpart.plot(trimmed.tree)                         # display the trimmed tree
```

This puts the tree on the screen, which you can manually prune with the mouse.  For details, see Chapter 9 "Trimming a tree with the mouse" of the rpart.plot package vignette
http://www.milbo.org/doc/prp.pdf.